# Find x which minimizes $||B - AX||_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, least-squares

I am finding a proper linear algebraic approach to find X that minimizes $||B-AX||_F$ where B satisfies a system of equation TB=H. I have given A, T, and H as  matrix from.

Comment: what is the structure of $B$.

Comment: A is mxn , C is mxm and G is mxp matrix

Comment: You don't have matrices $C$ or $G$ in this

Comment: opps.....sorry  A is mxn, T is mxm and H is mxp matrix.